# Can't pass event object down to if statement in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events, object, triggers

I have a function that is triggered by an click event... when clicked the function should get some information from the dom object that the click originated in.  All this works fine in firefox, but in IE8 it is not making it past the alert 3.

```
 function handleFileSelect(docEventTrigger) {        
    alert('1');
    if($('#tblListDocs tr input[value!=""]').length>0){
        alert('2');
        updateClicked(instanceID);
    }else{         
        alert('3');
        var docName, docVersion, docDate, docAuthor, formHTML, actionText, docActions, docResults, frmTarget, docRowCount;
        var files = docEventTrigger.target.files;  
        alert('4');    
            for (var iCount = 0, f; f = files[iCount]; iCount++) {
              alert('5');
                 STUFF HAPPENS HERE      
                 document.forms["frmUploadDoc"].submit();
              alert('6');       
    }
 }
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't support [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) for reading a local file. So, if you try this `var files = docEventTrigger.target.files; alert(files);`, you will always get `undefined` in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `target` attribute of event object is not cross browser. For IE, it should be `srcElement`.

To make the code cross browser, get either of those who is defined:

```
alert('3');
var sender, docName, docVersion, docDate, docAuthor, formHTML, actionText, docActions, docResults, frmTarget, docRowCount;
sender = docEventTrigger.target || docEventTrigger.srcElement;
var files = sender.files;  
alert('4');
```

That said, it won't help your specific case as explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14336063/447356).

To avoid having to mess around with the event, you can pass the object itself:

```
<input type="file" onchange="handleFileSelect(this);" />
```

Then the function parameter will already be the file input itself. (Same as `sender` in my above example)

Comment: I ended up removing all references to the file api.  Turns out the object was there the whole time, the files[] was just giving me an error. Guess I'm still trying to learn the best way to see what is and is not in the DOM.  Firebug makes it easy but in IE I have no idea what is available to use.

Comment: Cheers, IE does have Dev Tools (F12) but it's pretty limited compared to other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 (or IE9 for that matter) doesn't support any file APIs. It will throw an error in `files[iCount]` for a property access attempt on `undefined` value at latest.

Comment: Are there any solutions, or how would you reccomend I proceed?  I went ahead and added the inline onchange event to pass the object, and I also put in the target || srcElement that shadow wizard reccomended.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JSilva no, it is simply not supported